# Minimal DFA for language of all strings over $\{a,b\}$ whose penultimate symbol is $b$

Tags: automata, finite-automata

> Design a minimum state deterministic finite automata for accepting those strings over the alphabet $\{a, b\}$ whose last but one symbol is $b$.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Can you come up with *any* DFA at all? You could then apply a state minimization algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

Note that we have at least three states:

1. The second last character is $b$ so the tail 2-substring is either $ba$ or $bb$.
2. The last two characters are $ab$ (read at least one more character).
3. The last two characters are $aa$ (read at least two more characters).

which leads to the following DFA:
[image: Minimized DFA]

The above DFA contains minimal number of states if and only if it equals its minimization. Following [this page](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/automata_theory/dfa_minimization.htm) in *DFA Minimization using Equivalence Theorem* we have

$P_0 = \{(1, 2), (3)\}\\
P_1 = \{(1), (2), (3)\}$

In $P_1$ we used the fact that one single character may lead state 2 to an accepting state, whereas 1 does not "reach that far". Since $P_1$ gives no opportunity for further refinement, we may stop and we know that the DFA is minimized.

Answer (score -3):

[image]
Here second symbol from rhs is b or penultimate symbol is b

Comment: Why is this the answer? We discourage questions that are basically "Please do my homework for me" and, correspondingly, we discourage answers that don't even try to teach the asker how to solve such a problem for themself. In particular, how do you know that this automaton has the minimal number of states?